# How to make a viewModel to be Enumerable

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1. I'm passing a viewmodel to the razor view which is in the following:

public class BuyRequestViewModel
{

```
    public IEnumerable<BuyRequest> BuyRequestVM { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> PlatesVM { get; set; }
```

}

My problem is, as my viewmodel is not of type Ienumerable, I'm getting error in foreach in the razor view. The error is like the following:
ForEach statement can not operate on variables of type 'MyPanel.ViewModels.BuyRequestViewModel' because 'MyPanel.ViewModels.BuyRequestViewModel' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

And my razor view code is like below:

```
@model MyPanel.ViewModels.BuyRequestViewModel
<table id="myDummyTable" class="table m-table mytable table-striped table-bordered">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Region
            </th>
            <th>
                Zone
            <th>
                MyPlate
            </th>
  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BuyRequestVM.Select(x => x.Region))
                </td>
                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BuyRequestVM.Select(x => x.Zone))
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlatesVM)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here below is the Index action in my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{

    var bwrvm = new BuyRequestViewModel();

    List<string> platesList = new List<string>();

   
    var WasteAPIContext = _context.BuyRequest
       
        .Include(b => b.UserWasteUnitNavigation).ToList();

   bwrvm.BuyWasteRequestVM = WasteAPIContext;
    

    var plateData = _context.Car.Select(x => x.Plate).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < plateData.Count; i++)
    {
        //platesList.Add(plateData[i].ToString().Substring(2, 5));
        string temp = getPlateCharacter(plateData[i].ToString().Substring(2, 3));
        plateData[i].Remove(2, 3);
        string totalPlate = plateData[i].Insert(2, temp);

        platesList.Add(totalPlate);
    }

    bwrvm.PlatesVM = platesList;

    return View(bwrvm);
}
```

I appreciate of any help.

Comment: If you want to use your code,you need to pass List<BuyRequestViewModel> to view,and change `@model MyPanel.ViewModels.BuyRequestViewModel` to `@model IEnumerable<MyPanel.ViewModels.BuyRequestViewModel>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

should be

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BuyWasteRequestVM)
```

because Model == BuyRequestViewModel which contains 2 properties with lists.